# How to implement a template for math journal?

Tags: math-operators, journal

I want to design a math journal. Please give me a structure for it. For any article there is an individual .tex file. (Excuse me for my bad English :) )

Comment: Welcome to TeX! You can get some inspiration by looking at the IEEE formats: http://www.ieee.org/publications_standards/publications/authors/index.html

Comment: one possible approach: find a journal whose design you like.  determine whether that journal provides an author package.  use the provided documentclass as an inspiration.  (do *not* copy it directly; that could be considered violation of copyright unless the license is lppl, which should be identified in the class file itself.)  some publishers of math journals who provide latex author packages are: ams (`amsart.cls` is a "required" latex file), springer and elsevier.

Comment: This is an extremely general question.  You should specify more precisely what you need.